# Library Book Finder - Replace with highlighted String of Itself

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement, str-replace

I have a large string(over 255 char) called strLibrary.

This string has random text throughout and book locations within the library. The book locations are always in the format 'Floor###Column###Shelf###' IE Floor149Column423Shelf876. I want to be able to find all strings like Floor###Column###Shelf### and then highlight them in my rich text box named txtLibrary so they are easy to see.

***Note, the random text throughout may include the words "Floor" and or  "Column" and or "Shelf" and not be the string format Floor###Column###Shelf### so it is important to only highlight the strings in the format Floor###Column###Shelf###.***

In the past if I ever wanted to highlight a word(for example the word Book) in a rich text box I used the following:

```
strLibrary_RICH = Replace(strLibrary, "Book", "<font style =""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFF00"">"Book"</font>")

Me.txtLibrary = strLibrary_RICH
```

The 'strLibrary like Floor###Column###Shelf### function' only returns a TRUE/FALSE result. So using the following doesn't work:

```
Dim strLibrary_RICH     AS String
Dim strHighlight        AS String

If (strLibrary Like *Floor###Column###Shelf###*) Then

strHighlight = (strLibrary Like *Floor###Column###Shelf###*)

strLibrary_RICH = Replace(" & strHighlight & ","<font style =""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFF00"">" & strHighlight & "</font>")

End If

Me.txtLibrary = strLibrary_RICH
```

Is there a way to search for all strings like Floor###Column###Shelf### from within strLibrary and highlight them in rich text box txtLibrary?

Comment: You can use regex: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/#Replacing_a_Pattern_in_a_String

Comment: I cant get the regex to work when I include the "<font style =""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFF00"">"Floor        Column        Shelf        "</font>")

Comment: Are there more such occurrences in the analyzed string, or only one?

Comment: FaneDuru, there are many.

Comment: OK. I will prepare a function able to help.

Comment: FaneDuru, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses RegExp object with late binding so don't have to select reference library.

```
Function Highlight(strS As String, strP As String, strC As String)
Dim regexOne As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object
'Set regexOne = New RegExp
Set regexOne = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regexOne.Pattern = strP
regexOne.Global = True
Set Matches = regexOne.Execute(strS)
For Each Match In Matches
    strS = Replace(strS, Match.Value, "<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:#" & strC & ">" & Match.Value & "</font>")
Next
Highlight = strS
End Sub
```

Call the function:

`SELECT *, Highlight(fieldname, "Floor[0-9]+Column[0-9]+Shelf[0-9]+", "FFFFFF") AS HighlightText FROM table;`
or
`UPDATE table SET fieldname = Highlight(fieldname, "Floor[0-9]+Column[0-9]+Shelf[0-9]+", "FFFF00")`

Comment: June7, if I use this function how can I also search and replace multiple patterns? For example regexOne.Pattern = "Floor[0-9]+Column[0-9]+Shelf[0-9]+" and regexOne.Pattern = "Cats[0-9]+Dogs[0-9]+Lizards[0-9]+" in a different color like #FFFFFF is there a way to do this simultaneously?

Comment: June7, YOU ARE THE BEST!!!! I GOT IT TO WORK!!! with two pattern functions using "strLibrary_RICH = HighlightFunction1(strLibrary) + HighlightFunction2(strLibrary)" BAAAM works great!! I can highlight two different patterns with two different colors then. :) :)

Comment: Shouldn't need two functions. Add arguments to one function. See latest answer revision. I don't know why you would concatenate. Could call the function nested. How many different patterns at one time?

Comment: Yeah, u're right I was just duplicating the string :(

Comment: So can I add multiple patterns in for strP?

Comment: such as strP = [Floor[0-9]+Column[0-9]+Shelf[0-9] Cats[0-9]+Dogs[0-9]+Lizards[0-9]+] for two patterns pattern 1 = Floor[0-9]+Column[0-9]+Shelf[0-9]Cats[0-9]+ and pattern 2 = Cats[0-9]+Dogs[0-9]+Lizards[0-9]+

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you were trying to say now :) :) thanks its working now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the next function, please. It returns the occurrence position and the string length. I did not understood if numeric groups of the string to be found are always made by three digits. The function allows from 1 to 5 (easily to be increased if necessary...). According to the returned array, the string can be found using `Mid` standard VBA function:

```
Function extractFloorCh(strLibrary As String, Optional iStart As Long = 1) As Variant
   Dim lngFl As Long, arr(1) As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
Retry:
   lngFl = InStr(iStart, strLibrary, "Floor")
   If lngFl > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To 5
            If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strLibrary, lngFl + 4 + i, 1)) Then
               If Mid(strLibrary, lngFl + 4 + i, 6) <> "Column" Then
                    iStart = lngFl + 5: GoTo Retry
               Else
                    For j = 1 To 3
                        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strLibrary, lngFl + 4 + 5 + i, 1)) Then
                            For k = 1 To 5
                                If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strLibrary, lngFl + 4 + 14 + i + k, 1)) Then
                                    arr(0) = lngFl: arr(1) = 4 + 14 + i + k
                                    extractFloorCh = arr: Exit Function
                                End If
                            Next k
                        End If
                    Next
               End If
            End If
        Next i
   End If
End Function
```

The function can be called (and used) like in the next test Sub:

```
Sub testExtractStrHighlight()
  Dim x As String, y As String, strLibrary As String, arr As Variant, i As Long, strHighlight As String
  
  x = "Floor149Column423Shelf876": y = "Floor222Column444Shelf888"
  strLibrary = "dfgrty whatever  jutygt jhggffffFloorghjk" & x & "werer Column" & y & "tFlooruyuColumni"
  arr = 1 'for first function call...
  For i = 1 To 1000 'you can use here whatever you suppose to exceed the occurrences number
    If IsArray(arr) Then
       arr = extractFloorCh(strLibrary, arr(0) + arr(1))
    Else
        arr = extractFloorCh(strLibrary)
    End If
    If IsArray(arr) Then
       strHighlight = Mid(strLibrary, arr(0), arr(1))
       Debug.Print strHighlight
       'do here what you need with the returned string...
       '......
       '...
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Faneduru, Thank you!